# Should I destroy an instance even if its creation fails in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

Should I destroy an instance even if its creation fails in Vulkan?

Which one is correct:

**1:**

```
VkResult Result = vkCreateInstance( info, NULL, instance );
if(Result != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    vkDestroyInstance(Instance, NULL);
    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**2:**

```
VkResult Result = vkCreateInstance( info, NULL, instance );
if(Result != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the specification:

> If a command returns a run time error, it will leave any result pointers unmodified, unless other behavior is explicitly defined in the specification.

And since `VkCreateInstance` takes a `VkInstance*`, it will be left unmodified.